# Prevent Menu from closing immediately after onItemClicked is fired

Tags: android, contextmenu

i searched a while but wasn't able to finde a solution. I have something like toogle Button as MenuItem and i want to update it immediately when the user clicks on the Menu-Item.

Regarding to the Android docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html there is a flag called `FLAG_PERFORM_NO_CLOSE`.. i used it

```
menu.performIdentifierAction(R.id.myItem, Menu.FLAG_PERFORM_NO_CLOSE);
```

but you can imagine, nothing happens. Menu is closing as fast as before without updating.

It feels like Android isn't updating the Menu-View till it is closed. This Looks very ugly.. and the user isn't getting Feedback if Item is selected before Menu is reopening..

Can someone help with how i get it work?

The best solution for me would be if the Menu-Item is updating and the Menu Closes after let's say 200ms not immediatly.

**Update**

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
```

This is ne method which is fired when an Item is selected. It Looks like the Menu has it own handler behind the Scenes. I couldn't find anything which make it possible to delay the closing of the menu or even updating it.. hope it clear now

Comment: use handler on the code you want to delay a bit and it will work

Comment: @SarthakMittal ok, but it Looks like the Menu-Item isn't updating till the Menu is closed. My Phone isn't an old one. In my opinion the Menu stays Long enough open so that i would recognize a Change if the Menu-Item would be updated.. hope you understand me

Comment: i do understand you mike, but i don't understand your problem completely

Comment: still don't understand your ques properly, do you want to disable menu item click or something?

Comment: @SarthakMittal No i got something like a toggle button as a MenuItem, when the user clicks it, the Icon of the MenuItem should Switch. But the Item doesn't Switch when he clicks because the Menu isn't updating. But when the user opens the menu a second time then the Icon is updating. It's all just about the update of the view. The function behind the button is working immediatly, that's not the Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
  //write code you want to delay by 200 ms
  }
  }, 200);
```

For information on the working of Handler you can visit the Android Developer site.

Comment: i only have one more way in mind, try adding menu_object.requestLayout() just below the method call in which you wrote the code to change the UI

Comment: Not possible.. There is no valid Method for menu like requestLayout(). But thank you anyway..